# Formula to return specific value using multiple criteria?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: table data]

GOAL (please see attached image):

a. Generate the average between all scores that are from the 2nd quarter of 2019. (I tried using **AVERAGEIFS** here but I don't get to make it work)

b. Select latest year where a record is available (I used **MAX(A:A)** to generate this)

c. With a given year (e.g. I chose 2018), to generate the latest available quarter. (I do not know how to make the Quarters get selected if you need to satisfy the Year criteria then the priority criteria - Q4 first, then Q3, then Q2, then Q1. Like for 2019,  Q3 is the latest available.)

d. Make this all work even is there are blanks.

I am trying to relearn Excel. If you can help me, this would mean a lot. Thank you.

Comment: please [edit] the post to include the formula you tried.

Answer (score 0):

a.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(C2:C10;B2:B10;"Q2";A2:A10;2019)
```

b.

```
=MAXIFS(A2:A10;C2:C10;"<>")
```

c. Here I would add one helper column (col.D):

```
=INT(RIGHT(B2;1))
```

And then simply:

```
="Q"&MAXIFS(D2:D10;A2:A10;2018)
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help... totally appreciate this

Comment: I have a problem though. I am using Excel 2013 and MAXIFS is not available. Is there an alternative formula to this?

Comment: Here's what I did for the MAXIFS alternative:

b. {=MAX(IF(C2:C10<>"0";A2:A10))}

c. {="Q"&MAX(IF(A2:A10<>"0";D2:D10))}

I hope I am doing it correctly. It seems to generate the same outcome.